# How often does the string repeat in the list of vectors? (in R)

Tags: r, string

I have a list of vectors with the following structure

```
[953] "c(\"15768\", \"11999\")"  
[954] "c(\"18012\", \"4761\", \"1792\", \"18085\", \"18002\", \"18018\", \"8818\", \"8696\")"  
[955] "c(\"735\", \"6073\", \"18007\", \"18046\", \"18087\")"
```

As you can see, each number is a string. These strings repeate in different vectors. What I need is to find out how often each string repeats over the data I have.

I have tried to `table`, but it doesn't work the way I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `vector` of single strings, then an option is `str_extract_all` to extract all the numeric part, `unlist` and get the `table`

```
library(stringr)   
tbl <- sort(table(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(vec1, 
       "\\d+")))), decreasing = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sort(table(unlist(regmatches(vec1, gregexpr("\\d+", vec1)))), decreasing = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
vec1 <- c("c(\"15768\", \"11999\")", "c(\"18012\", \"4761\", \"1792\", \"18085\", \"18002\", \"18018\", \"8818\", \"8696\")", 
"c(\"735\", \"6073\", \"18007\", \"18046\", \"18087\")")
```

Comment: ```table(unlist(str_extract_all(lst1, "\\d+")))``` works! Do you know how to arrange the frequencies in the descending order?

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha  You can use `sort`  Updated the answer

Comment: Option with ```stringr``` works better. I sustect that the ```base R``` option is flawed since it gives me really strange output with unexisting variables.

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha  May be in your original dataset, there are some values that are not picked by `gregexpr`